# Different Results In Exporting Data From Google Analytics 4

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have tried using Google Analytics Data Api - and issue with it is that the numbers don't much up with what I get from api and from what I see on web ui of Google Analytics. I even tried query explorer for Google Analytics Data Api but got less results again.

From what I am assuming and come to know that google sampling applies on GA Data Api (Although I have results of a day in few hundreds only). Now I heard there is no option to control sampling in GA Data API but there was in GA Reporting API by controlling sampling size option. So I decided to use that. But to my surprise Reporting API only takes View ID and I only had Property ID because I was using GA4 (can't enable universal analytics).

This takes me down to what? I tried Management api and it is for controlling options but not to view data. I tried to import data into Looker and exported from there to myself. But Looker has same results I get from query explorer which are less than web ui of Google Analytics.

I want to do this programatically so just can't use manual export option of GA4.

Need help in finding best way to do it !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

I have done this same thing in google analytics data api, query explorer as well as ga web ui. Ga web ui shows the most results. While query explorer and google analytics data api shows the same after sampling. Attached screenshots for reference.

**GA WEB UI _ QUERY**

[image: GA WEB UI _ QUERY]

**GA WEB UI _ RESULTS EXPORTED TO CSV**

[image: GA WEB UI _ RESULTS EXPORTED TO CSV]

**QUERY EXPLORER_ QUERY**

[image: QUERY EXPLORER_ QUERY]

**QUERY EXPLORER_ RESULTS**

[image: QUERY EXPLORER_ RESULTS]

**GA4 DATA API_ RESULTS**

[image: GA4 DATA API_ RESULTS]

**EVEN TRIED 3rd PARTY SERVICE Supermetrics GOT SAME**

[image: EVEN TRIED 3rd PARTY SERVICE Supermetrics GOT SAME]

**Here is code for GAT DATA API:**
`

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
    from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
    import pandas as pd
    from collections import defaultdict
    SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
    KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'MY_GA.json'
    property_id = 'properties/266233569'
    dimensions = ["date","platform","customEvent:order_id"]
    metrics =  ['sessions']
    request = {
      "requests": [
        {
          "dateRanges": [
            {
              "startDate": "2022-10-19",
              "endDate": "2022-10-19"
            }
          ],
          "dimensions": [{'name': name} for name in dimensions],
          "metrics": [{'name': name} for name in metrics],
         "limit": 10000,
          "return_property_quota": True,
          "keep_empty_rows": True
        }
      ]
    }
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)    
analytics = build('analyticsdata', 'v1beta', 
credentials=credentials)
    response = 
analytics.properties().batchRunReports(property=property_id, 
body=request).execute()
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a GA4 limitation. If you're considering third-party solutions, Able CDP has its own tracking that connects to BigQuery (so easily accessible in Looker) and provides raw tracking data without sampling.

Comment: BigQuery doesn't provide level of attribution I want.

Comment: ? BigQuery doesn't provide any attribution. I meant using non-GA4 attribution with BigQuery as a data warehouse to facilitate getting third-party tracking data into Looker.